# dual boot 2x windows10 on UEFI/GPT

Tags: windows-10, bootloader, dualboot

As I am quite used to dual/multiple boot-options (boot-managers etc) in BIOS/MBR environment, but not in UEFI/GPT, I wonder if and how the following can work:

I copied (cloned) my windows-system partition(A) on my HDD to a second partition(B). Now I want to "simply" boot either (A) or (B), while the "inactive" windows-partition being hidden.

Any help highly appreciated!